# how to to fix Minimum Package Size error during OpenFL Android compilation (flashdevelop)?

Tags: android, android-ndk, adt, haxe

So I'm building a basic OpenFL project (essentially a template in flashdevelop 4.4.3). When I compile to windows/flash/html5 works fine. Once I target Android, I get this:

BUILD FAILED: Application package 'Fscape' must have a minimum of 2 segments.

This is the ANT generated build.xml. As you can see, each package name does have more than two "segments" (separated by dots).

```
            <gettarget
            androidJarFileOut="project.target.android.jar"
            androidAidlFileOut="project.target.framework.aidl"
            bootClassPathOut="project.target.class.path"
            targetApiOut="project.target.apilevel"
            minSdkVersionOut="project.target.minSdkVersion" />
```

I did have to add "target" to project.target.minSdkVersion (the last line in that XML attribute list). Do I have to clear this in some way (it's not refreshing?)? I tried deleting it altogether or naming it unrelated package names like some message boards suggested but the error persists.

I'm running the latest Android SDK/NDK but also with all the older SDKs for compatibility. I'm using Flashdevelop 4.4.3 to compile against Haxe. All SDK's are the latest as of this post, including JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bit confusing that the compilation error threw in the build.xml and not the application.xml. It makes total sense now that I know the build.xml pulls attributes from the application.xml

Need three segments separated by dots in the package attribute in application.xml

```
<meta title="Fscape" package="com.Fscape.game" version="1.0.0" company=""
```